# Bootstrap carousel interval false not working (complete bootstrap)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel, intervals

I am using the complete bootstrap 3 css and js.

```
//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css
//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js
```

I am loading a carousel after page load using ajax.

```
<div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">');
..
</div>
```

Upon success I am calling this code to stop cycling on mouseover:

```
$('#carousel').one('mousemove', function() { PauseCarousel(); } );
```

The function to pause is:

```
function PauseCarousel() {  $('.carousel').carousel({ pause: true,interval: false});  }
```

The event fires ok on mouseover.
And yet, the carousel continues to slide.

Any help would be appreciated.

Kembreg